# How to take a field value and use it as a parameter in a URL

Tags: ms-access

So I am trying to implement an automatic search of ebay completed listings of an item, based on the value of a field in my table.

I am using access and I cant work out how to do this. I have tried changing the thing to [Field1] and messing around with the settings but I cant get it to work.

This is the url I need but I need the **xbox%20one** to be replaced with a field value.

http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&LH_ItemCondition=3000&_nkw=**xbox%20one**&LH_Complete=1&rt=nc&_trksid=p2045573.m1684

The field I need to change is _nkw= as shown in picture

Any ideas would be appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Just change as shown in photo where in between the brackets put the field you need.
[image]

Comment: Mark it as correct answer and get your points :-)